# Forces on body above body moving at constant velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image]

Let's say the system is moving at constant velocity. What are the forces applied on B? Is there a static friction force? I find it hard to imagine what is happening to object B. $\Sigma F$ is $0$ on A and on B too since it moves with constant velocity. The only one who can apply force on it is A.

If A was to apply force on B, then there would be also an opposite force applied by A (so $\Sigma F$ is $0$ on B) so it is a contradiction thus no force is applied on B.

However, lets look at the molecule level. B's molecules are moved by A molecules. So A must apply force on B! Like in this picture:

[image]

A's surface must move B's surface to the direction of the movement, otherwise B would not move.

I'm really confused.

Comment: I am confused about your question. According to Newton's third law there is a reaction force to every force. So if B applies a force on A, then A also has to apply a force on B. On Earth's surface that force is simply opposite to the weight of B and it's needed, otherwise B would be falling to the core of the Earth. The microscopic roughness of the surfaces of A and B converts these normal forces into friction parallel to the surface. All of this is completely independent of the motion of A/B, which is an inertial system dependent quantity, anyway.

Comment: What are the initial velocities of the blocks? ($v_{0,A}$ and $v_{0,B}$)

Comment: @CuriousOne A's surface must move B's surface to the direction of the movement, otherwise B would not move. I now also clarified this in the question.

Comment: @lucas I don't really understand why does this matter. Let's assume for simplicity that we are talking about them moving in same constant velocity both.

Comment: You said all of this is moving at constant velocity, so no force to move B is needed... I am even more confused now.

Comment: @CuriousOne I get what you are saying. I thought about this in the molecule level, but even then if molecules are at constant velocity then there is no "pushing" force that they apply on  each other. 
To clarify my misunderstanding - I imagined the system at constant velocity at molecule level as if it was accelerating so molecules of A push molecules of B and also the opposite. If we are speaking about constant velocity then of course no pushing between molecules. This was my mistake.

Comment: Ivan, I think you have a lot of confusion about forces.  You really need to discuss this with your teacher, or a classmate who understands the problem.

Comment: ... or be more careful about how you phrase the question.  What is the system?  As currently phrased, *There are no friction forces.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blocks initial velocities are zero (i.e. the blocks start to move from rest), then it is impossible for block B to move with constant velocity. Because the only horizontal force acting on it (if there was) is friction force due to block A. We have:
$$\Sigma F_B=m_Ba_B$$
If block B moves with constant velocity, then $a_B=0$

Thus, friction force acting on block B due to block A will be zero. On the other hand, If the contact surface is rough, then there mustn't be relative motion between A and B, otherwise certainly there will be a friction force between A and B. So, if the blocks start to move from rest, it is impossible for block B to move with constant velocity. But, if the blocks have the same initial velocity, then it is possible for them to continue their motion with the same velocity and it is possible resultant force ($\Sigma F_B=F_{\textrm{friction}}$) acting on B to be zero even if the contact surface is rough.

Answer (score 1):

I thought about this in the molecule level, but then if molecules are at constant velocity then there is no "pushing" force that they apply on each other. To clarify my misunderstanding - I imagined the system at constant velocity at molecule level as if it was accelerating so molecules of A push molecules of B and also the opposite. If we are speaking about constant velocity then of course no pushing between molecules. This was my mistake.